# OpenTelemetry Python Metric Counter not picked up by Prometheus

Tags: python, prometheus, metrics, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I have a simple python app, that I'm trying to use to learn about instrumentation. This is a short live app that I will run just by running `python3 app.py`, my goal is to keep track in metric counter about how many times I run this app, at least this is the goal for this simple app. But it seems like the counter always get set to 0 again whenever the app stop and I rerun the app. So 2 questions:

- Is Instrumentation mainly used for a continuous long running app like web app? Will this work for CLI application that stop once it is finished its task?
- Since this app end really quick it does not seems like prometheus pick up the data, I need to add `time.sleep(5)` before it shows up, even then it's a hit and miss sometimes it shows up sometimes it's not. if I don't have time.sleep, it won't even pick it up. I tried changing `prometheus.yml` config for scrape interval

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1s #or 0s1ms, both does not seems to work properly
```

This is the code python code `app.py`

```
from opentelemetry import metrics
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import (
    ConsoleMetricExporter,
    PeriodicExportingMetricReader,
)

from opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus import PrometheusMetricReader
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import SERVICE_NAME, Resource

import time

# Service name is required for most backends
resource = Resource(attributes={
    SERVICE_NAME: "my-python-app-service"
})

# Start Prometheus client
start_http_server(port=8000, addr="localhost")

# Initialize PrometheusMetricReader which pulls metrics from the SDK
# on-demand to respond to scrape requests
reader = PrometheusMetricReader()
provider = MeterProvider(resource=resource, metric_readers=[reader])
metrics.set_meter_provider(provider)

meter = provider.get_meter("your-meter-name")

def counter():
    counter = meter.create_counter(name="some-prefix-counter", description="TODO")

    # while True:
    counter.add(1)
    time.sleep(5) # if I remove this prometheus won't pick up any data I think because the scrape is not even run yet?

counter()
```

This is `prometheus.yml`

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 1s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus-demo"
    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8000"]
```

Comment: I encourage you to read the Prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/). It's comprehensive and spending some time to understand the basics will be a good investment. Prometheus principally scrapes targets (like your app) to acquire metrics. Although you can tweak the frequency (`scrape_interval`), you can't fundamentally control when Prometheus will scrape a target and therefore, in your case, it's improbable that your app will be running when Prometheus attempts to scrape it.

Comment: Prometheus does support [pushing metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/#pushing-metrics) but you should only use this mechanism when you must.

Comment: See [How does a Prometheus Counter work](https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work/) to understand why, even though scraped (!) values for Counters may have been reset, Prometheus continues to correctly represent the Counter's value.

Comment: For perhaps a quicker way to get started, the Prometheus Python SDK includes a very straightforward [example](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#three-step-demo)

Comment: Regarding first part of your question: you recreate counter every time you start application, and since you don't provide initial value - it will always be zero at start. Prometheus doesn't do arithmetic on metrics while scraping. You say it's value is 1, and prometheus stores this 1, not `previous value + 1`.

Comment: @DazWilkin I think using pushgateway is what I need. and I can see it's getting pushed. However how am I supposed to query it to see the lifetime count? I tried using increase(), I tries using sum_over_time() it's all not returning the number of count I expected. imagine if I do counter.inc() everytime I run the script, I'd like to see the number of time I run the script. any idea how to query that?

Comment: @Harts, you have to either request last value from prometheus every time, or store it elsewhere.  Or convert it to long lived service, where count is stored in memory, and task executed in thread. for example.

Comment: @markalex how do I request last value in python? also, how come some stackoverflow mentioned prometheus reset counter to 0, but using increase(my_counter_total[100d]), it will show the total counter? (though it is not the case for me)

Comment: It can be done with curl like this: `curl 'https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/query?query=last_over_time(some-prefix-counter\[7d\])&time=1683754045'`. Rewrite it to python yourself.

Comment: `increase(my_counter_total[100d])` will work, if your counter actually counts something. Yours counter is always 1, and as a result Prometheus don't see any resets.